# HashMap values not updating

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Map object where I use integers as the keys, and Lists as the corresponding values. Here is my code.

```
Map<Integer, List<Double>> dataDouble = new HashMap<Integer, List<Double>>();
List<Double> dubList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for(double i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    dubList.add(i);

dataDouble.put(1, dubList);
//dubList.clear(); 

for(int i = 10; i < 16; i++)
    dubList.add(i);

dataDouble.put(2, dubList);

Set<Integer> keyset = dataDouble.keySet();

for(Integer key : keyset) {
    System.out.println("\t\tKEY: " + key);
    List<Double> finList = dataDouble.get(key);
    for(double value : finList)
        System.out.println("VALUE: " + value);    

    }   
}
```

If I do not include the clear statement then the second list is not updated, and I get 2 block of 1 to 10 in the print statements. If I do add the clear command, only 10-15 is printed in the two blocks.

My question is, why does the clear command clear data already added to the Map, and also why does adding new data to the list and putting it on the Map not actually change the values?

Edit: I know I am using double instead of int, in my actual project I am dealing with double values

Comment: Lists are objects. You only ever create one list `dubList`. No matter how many times you add it to `dataDouble`, it's going to be the same object, the same list.

Comment: So the values in the map are not actually set, instead just pointing to the object itself?

Comment: @PeytonC. correct, since it is pointing to a reference of the object, when you add it to the list you are just adding the reference to the `ArrayList` named `dubList` which has 0-15 in it since you never initialized a new `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't putting a different `ArrayList` under the different keys in the `HashMap`. You're putting the ***same*** `ArrayList` under each one. That means that any change that gets made to it will be reflected in all of them (since they're all the same object).

If you want to have multiple different `List`s, you need to create a new one with `new ArrayList<>()`. So replace the line where you `clear` it with `dubList = new ArrayList<>()`, and it will correctly give you a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same object for all the entries you're adding to the map.

After having added it, change the `List` the reference is pointing to.

```
dataDouble.put(1, dubList);
dubList = new ArrayList<>();   <--- HERE

for(int i = 10; i < 16; i++)
    dubList.add(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a reference to the same `ArrayList` named dubList, and adding that reference to your map twice. You need to have two seperate `ArrayList` declarations.

```
Map<Integer, List<Double>> dataDouble = new HashMap<Integer, List<Double>>();
List<Double> dubList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for(double i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   dubList.add(i);

dataDouble.put(1, dubList);

//add a new ArrayList
List<Double> dubList2 = new ArrayList<Double>();

for(int i = 10; i < 16; i++)
   dubList2.add(i);

dataDouble.put(2, dubList2);

Set<Integer> keyset = dataDouble.keySet();

for(Integer key : keyset) {
   System.out.println("\t\tKEY: " + key);
   List<Double> finList = dataDouble.get(key);
   for(double value : finList)
      System.out.println("VALUE: " + value);
   }
}
```